# May a Web Worker render on WebGL-Canvas?

Tags: javascript, webgl, web-worker

I don't understand how web-workers works... Are web-workers parallel or just preempted?

Is it safe for a web-workers to render to a webgl context?

If I have only a web-worker rendering to webgl context, and my main "thread" is not invoking the worker also, is it safe to the web-worker to render to the webgl context?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using WebGL from inside a Web Worker: is it possible ? How?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844886/using-webgl-from-inside-a-web-worker-is-it-possible-how)

Comment: To answer part of your question that hasn't been directly addressed yet: Yes, workers are parallel. It's as close as you can get to an actual "thread" in Javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844886/using-webgl-from-inside-a-web-worker-is-it-possible-how) question has an answer that basically states you can't use webgl from a web worker as web workers don't have access to the DOM and you have to call *getContext()* on a canvas object to get the webgl context.

Comment: this is outdated. `OffscreenCanvas` allows you to render in a web worker

Answer (score 5):

When a Web Worker is created, you give it a URI pointing to a JavaScript file.  It loads that JavaScript file in a new OS-level thread.  You can't control affinity to specific cores or thread priorities, (as of this writing), but the underlying Thread created is real and unfettered.  By default, JavaScript running in a Web Worker's thread has NO access to the DOM: you are not given access to the window object nor any DOM-related Classes.

The semantics of the Web Worker thread make it nearly completely unmoored from the default DOM thread.  First thing that's interesting is that the Web Worker can run in 100% CPU usage infinite loops without worrying about freezing up the UI.  This means the dreaded "Warning: Unresponsive script" message box cannot be triggered by a Web Worker!

The tradeoff of being unmoored is your ability to synchronize and communicate between DOM and worker threads is limited.  The explicit conduit between worker and DOM is the postMessage() API for sending data and the onmessage event for receiving events.  You can postMessage with strings and objects where your data is cloned from source thread's heap into target thread's heap.  onmessage events are only received by your Web Worker when it is idle.  This means, in order for onmessage events to be delivered from the DOM to your Web Worker in a timely fashion, the worker must yield frequently; this may put a wrinkle in the way you want to write your code.

It's important to understand that there are a special class of "Transferable Objects" in modern JavaScript implementations where objects that you send to postMessage() are not cloned, but rather ownership of the object is transferred from one thread to another.  These are the types of data you want to send to postMessage() whenever possible; any time data is cloned when calling postMessage(), you create TONS of garbage to be GC'd and system performance will suffer.

The collection of Transferable Object types out there has been steadily growing, and the Mozilla Development Network, WhatWG, and W3C are great places to watch the spec research in this area.  I couldn't even tell you all of the things that can be Transferred across threads in the browser nowadays, but if I made you a comprehensive list, it'd likely be out of date in a year or less.

Regarding your original question, on Firefox 44+, you can now partially transfer a Canvas to a WebWorker via the HTMLCanvasElement#transferControlToOffscreen function.  transferControlToOffscreen creates a Transferable OffscreenCanvas object that you can postMessage over to a Web Worker.  On the Web Worker, you can acquire a webgl CanvasContext and issue drawing commands to the canvas from the worker thread without having direct access to the actual canvas tag's DOM that still lives over with the DOM thread.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/transferControlToOffscreen

https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/01/webgl-off-the-main-thread/